# Java ORM: modify record in generic way

Tags: java, generics, orm, ormlite

Which Java ORM support **not-typesave** modification of object?

I want to modify objects / records in a generic way, where the `fieldName`   is a string input parameter, and value is a generic `AnyObject` parameter. Do you know something like this?

I.e. in `Core Data` in iOS it can work like this:

[image]

I went though `ormlite` [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-ormlite-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and I just realized, need to get the appropriate Dao, to insert an item:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how ActiveJDBC works. Check out at http://javalite.io.